# File inputting matrix(text file) into ArrayList

Tags: java, matrix, arraylist, file-io, matrix-multiplication

So I have a text file which contains two matrices and I need to input that into an ArrayList to do a matrix multiplication. I'm new to JAVA and I don't know where to start with. I know that I need to use FileReader and BufferedReader to input the file, but how do I store the matrices into ArrayList? Can anyone go over step by step?

Comment: You're question is quite broad and involves a problem that is composed of many steps, likely too many to allow a focused decent answer. Your best bet is to decompose your problem into its smaller constituent steps and then try to solve each step one at a time.

Comment: .... oftentimes solving them in isolation from the main program. Then if you get stuck in a single step, you can more easily ask a much more focused question, *with your pertinent code*, and you'll more likely get a decent answer.

Comment: We do not know what the text file contents look like.

Answer (score 0):

1. First you should find how to read file and read file using required classes that is FileReader and BufferedReader.
2. And once you start getting matrices numbers from file you can get row of matrices into a ArrayList.
3. Then you store all row ArrayList into one single ArrayList, so that you will have one ArrayList per matrix.
4. Once you stored numbers into ArrayList, you can manipulate it as you want.
5. You can find code for all this operations on stackoverflow itself.